# GCC "AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow" when initializing struct

Tags: c++, gcc, malloc

I've been writing an VM/Interpreter combination thingy, I don't know how to exactly describe it.

Everything behaved as it should, now before I have hundreds of lines of code, I wanted to go into Garba Collection, because there were some pointers which somehow got lost, in some way. Not that I didn't delete pointers, I created, but they somehow got lost in the proccess of interpreting/running the code.

So, I wanted to track them. I wrote my own "Memory Manager" in some way, it's just a `std::vector`, where I collect all pointers in.

To track and allocate pointers, I have following code:

```cpp
struct MemBlock {
    bool free;
    void* ptr;
    size_t size;
};

std::vector<MemBlock*> mem;
size_t max_size;
size_t mem_size;
int count = 0;

void mem_init(size_t maxSize) {
    max_size = size/sizeof(MemBlock*);
}

void* mem_alloc(size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        MemBlock* block = mem[i];

        if (block->free) {
            mem_size -= block->size;
            mem_size += size;
            block->free = false;
            block->ptr = malloc(size);
            block->size = size;

            if (block->ptr == nullptr) {
                throw std::exception();
            }
            return block->ptr;
        }
    }

    void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(size));

    if (ptr == nullptr) {
        throw PointerNullException();
    }

    MemBlock* block = (MemBlock*) malloc(sizeof(MemBlock));
    *block = (MemBlock) {
        false,
        ptr,
        size
    };

    mem_size += size;
    count++;

    mem.push_back(block);
    return block->ptr;
}
```

But as soon, as I use `mem_alloc()` and initialize the object inside of the pointer:

```cpp
Int* i = (Int*) mem_alloc(sizeof(Int));
*i = (Int) {};    // -- Here
i->value = atoi(advance().c_str());
```

The GCC AdressSanitizer shows following error:

```
==5939==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000098 at pc 0x555963d82fc5 bp 0x7fff4ec39070 sp 0x7fff4ec39060
WRITE of size 4 at 0x602000000098 thread T0
```

If I remove said line, then it just occurs on the nex line. The the pointer does point to a valid memory location, if not it should've had thrown an exception.
I'm sure that I missed something/did something wrong, of course.

But I don't know what. This is how I learned it, or at least what I understood...

**Edit:**
This would be a minimal reproducible Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

struct Object {
    const char* type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Primitive : Object {
    T value;
};

struct Int : Primitive<int> {
    const char* type = "int";
};

struct MemBlock {
    bool free;
    void* ptr;
    size_t size;
};

std::vector<MemBlock*> mem;
size_t mem_size = 0;
int count = 0;

void* mem_alloc(size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        MemBlock* block = mem[i];

        if (block->free) {
            mem_size -= block->size;
            mem_size += size;
            block->free = false;
            block->ptr = malloc(size);
            block->size = size;

            if (block->ptr == nullptr) {
                throw std::exception();
            }
            return block->ptr;
        }
    }

    void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(size));

    MemBlock* block = (MemBlock*) malloc(sizeof(MemBlock));
    *block = (MemBlock) {
        false,
        ptr,
        size
    };

    mem_size += size;
    count++;

    mem.push_back(block);

    std::cout << "HI" << std::endl;    
    return block->ptr;
}
void mem_free(void* ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        MemBlock* block = mem[i];

        if (block->ptr == ptr) {
            free(ptr);

            mem_size -= block->size;
            block->size = 0;
            block->ptr = nullptr;
            block->free = true;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Create new Integer-Object
    Int* i = (Int*) mem_alloc(sizeof(Int));


    std::cout << "[Pointer]: " << i << std::endl;

    *i = (Int) {};
    i->value = 5;

    std::cout << "[Value]: " << i->value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm having to hack this up a lot to get a compliable example. That's offering up plenty of opportunities to accidentally add bugs and give you a wrong answer) or accidentally fix the bug (and give you no answer). Consider constructing a [mre]. Odds are good that just making the MRE will reduce the noise enough for you to find and fix the mistake, but if not, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: `void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(size));` You sure you want `sizeof` there? Would help if you put together a [mcve] that demonstrated the problem.

Comment: `*block = ...` is undefined behavior.  `malloc` doesn't create objects, it only allocates memory so there is no `MemBlock` being point to by `block` for you to assign to.

Comment: I have added a minimal reproducible example.

I'm sure, that I want to use ``*block = ...``, due to it creating the object at the allocated memory. From what I've read many times.

Comment: Replace `Int* i = (Int*) mem_alloc(sizeof(Int)); *i = (Int) {};    // -- Here` with placement new into the  block returned by `mem_alloc` and things might improve (alignment issues not withstanding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) and [Richar Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten), I've got the solution.

In `mem_alloc()` I've used `sizeof(size)` to allocate memory to the pointer, which of course is wrong. I guess my head was pretty much off after hours of coding.

But I guess this problem is now solved.